# Mint - can't click anything

Tags: mouse, linux-mint

My problem in Mint 17 is that, on occasion, I will suddenly lose the ability to click anything. The mouse still moves, and hovering works fine, but the buttons don't do anything. The only way to fix the problem seems to be to restart the machine.

I'm using a Logitech G600, and was having no problems for about 2 weeks before the problems suddenly started, and now I can't use the computer for more than an hour or so without having to reboot.

Any input is greatly appreciated.